How do we determine our actual degree of belief?
The SEP talks about the notion of a degree of belief, or credence in a proposition.

One common way of formalizing this idea is by means of a scale from 0 to 1, where 0 indicates absolute certainty in the falsity of a proposition, 1 indicates absolute certainty in its truth, and .5 indicates that the subject regards the proposition just as likely to be true as false. This number then indicates one’s credence or degree of belief. Standard approaches equate degree of belief with the maximum amount the subject would, or alternatively should, be willing to wager on a bet that pays nothing if the proposition is false and 1 unit if the proposition is true. So, for example, if the subject thinks that the proposition “the restaurant is open” is three times more likely to be true than false, they should be willing to pay no more than $0.75 for a wager that pays nothing if the restaurant is closed and $1 if it is open. Consequently, the subject’s degree of belief is .75, or 75%. Such a formalized approach to degree of belief has proven useful in decision theory, game theory, and economics. Standard philosophical treatments of this topic include Jeffrey (1983) and Skyrms (2000).

So there seems to be two possible ways we assess degree of belief: with the mathematics that lies behind odds, and with actual actions taken in the form of bets. So, in any given situation the odds are merely considered a hypothetical since unless a bet actually is made, we don't know what we believe if haven't decided to bet, right? If we don’t bet, do we know what our actual degree of belief in a proposition is in the first place?

You ask: "how do we know what our actual degree of belief in a proposition is in the first place?" - If you yourself do not know how firm your belief is, how shall an external source find the answer for you?

Can we know that we saw red yesterday, and it was the same red that we see today. After all, we cannot actually time travel and verify it. And as we trust our memory, faulty though it is, we'll just have to trust our imagination to let ourselves know how we would hypothetically behave, as we do in any planning. And yes, we may guess wrong, as with everything else, and/or our bet may change when it comes to making it. Italicizing and adding "actually" do not do the work you expect of them.

@Conifold Being facetious also doesn’t do much in changing the fact that the reliability of memory is much different from the reliability of how we would act given certain bets that never occur

@JoWehler You are missing the point like Conifold. Why assume that there is such a thing as “how firm” your belief is in the first place? Perhaps belief is binary and I know that I would bet on it, but not how much I would bet on it, which is what a degree of belief represents as per the article

@Syed - I don't want to be facetious or patronizing, but you should read up both on probability theory (and its foundations) and on psychology. Also, ask your neighbors, friends or family how sure they are that it will (or will not) rain tomorrow (assuming it ever rains where you live). Then tell them that what they're saying is nonsense, since it will either rain or not, so "how sure" makes no sense. See how they react.

@Syed - Just to be clear - I'm pretty sure you will have read my previous comment as either patronizing or kind of facetious. I sincerely apologize. I'm not very sure you will have believed my apology just now. But please do believe it -- if it really bothered you.

@syed - Just do the experiment. You  might learn something.

@mudskipper the only thing I’m learning is that your analogies are as nonsensical as believing in a flat earth. People have hard emotional reactions when their beliefs are threatened: so what?

I think you're trying to say that in some way, our actions are the true determinant of our belief, and that unless we act, we cannot know what we believe. Is that right?

@JD yes, partially, thank you for getting it! When there are immediate practical consequences for what you believe, those beliefs may be accurately measured than without. For example, our “beliefs” may be different in an actual situation with money on the line, and I just fail to see how one can reliably then know their actual degree of belief. Comparing this to our experience seems fallacious since that kind of knowledge has more basis

I think I've revised the language to clarify the question. Hopefully that staves off closure. Feel free to roll back.

You seem to be suggesting that you 'actually' need to place a bet in order to form an assessment of a probability. That's rather like saying that you actually have to jump in the sea to imagine getting wet.

I created a meta thread about this question. I'd like to see it reopened.

This question seems clear enough to me after JD's edit. Willingness to bet is central to modern interpretations of probability.

@causative, but the question is asking about how you determine your level of belief about something, and it is possible to hold a strong belief but not be willing to place a bet. For example, if a person believes that gambling is 100% wrong they would not be willing to place a bet because of their belief about it.

@MichaelHall True, that presents a challenge. Still, the person may be willing to accept certain other trade-offs that are equivalent to bets, though this makes their beliefs harder to discover through external observation.

@causative, I get it, in the theme of "actions speak louder than words", but WRT "discover through external observation" they question asks "how do we determine our actual degree of belief" which implies internal self reflection vs assessment from the outside.

@MichaelHall what about internal self reflection is not philosophy to you? And the question was with respect to the linked framework that defines a degree of belief as the willingness to bet a certain amount. If you have a problem with that, you should address the philosophical arguments for a degree of belief system, instead of writing unproductive (and now deleted) comments

What about my comments indicates I believe that internal self reflection is not philosophy?  What about my comments indicates I have any sort of problem?

@MichaelHall you deleted your earlier comments (or they were deleted) so there’s no point in continuing this

FWIW, I didn't delete it... and I stand by it as an attempt to provide some needed balance, (seasoned with light sarcasm in an obviously rejected attempt at humor...) to counter the tendency on this site to inflate and unnecessarily complicate mundane topics.  Sometimes a dose of reality is needed to make a point.

@MichaelHall perhaps what you consider an obvious form of reality needs to be questioned then. When people cannot defend their viewpoints and have to resort to rejected attempts at humour or sarcasm, it could be a sign that their viewpoints had no basis in the first place

Oh, but I can defend my viewpoints. I choose to defend them using brevity and common sense.  Case in point, you earlier insinuated a belief that I had some sort of undisclosed "problem", yet according to your own question you wouldn't have any way to determine the actual degree of this belief without placing a wager.  Since you expressed this belief in your comment, should I presume that you have placed a wager of some sort?  Don't you see the absurdity in this line of thinking?!

@MichaelHall I think that would represent a fairly good answer, should this question be reopened. (Or at least, I've encountered it before in the context of bayesian rationality, where a lot of arguments go something like "well, all your beliefs should be consistent, because what if a little devil froze time and up and asked if you wanted to wager $10 on a guaranteed-to-lose series of bets" and a lot of the counterarguments go "why would I ever accept bets from devils who pop up and offer me bets in the first place!?")

@MichaelHall well not necessarily. You’re presuming the existence of a degree of belief in the first place. The question was with respect to the framework. If we’re talking about personal viewpoints, I don’t think it even makes sense to represent belief as degrees. I think all beliefs are bets but only comparatively. For example, I may bet that God exists compared to God not existing. Or if I had to pick between the earth being a sphere and me dying next year, I might bet on the former. But none of this implies that a number or degree needs to be attached to belief

"You’re presuming the existence of a degree of belief in the first place."  No, that's what your question presumes in the title.  "I don’t think it even makes sense to represent belief as degrees."  To a certain extent I agree... I will add that we don't have to bet to hold a belief as your question insinuates.  However, if you do choose to wager it becomes prudent to assess the probability of the thing you are betting on before you put any money at risk.  How much you actually wager may reveal a subconscious bias, which I think you are getting at in the question?

@MichaelHall well you can’t fit everything into the title but the body gives context that the question is with respect to that framework linked from the SEP. Secondly, I don’t think we have to bet either, but I still think of beliefs as “would be” comparative bets. If you believe in X, it’s effectively the same as betting on X rather than the negation of X, even if you never make that bet in practice. Also, it seems more plausible to accurately know whether you’d bet on one option vs another as compared to accurately knowing how much money you’d bet on one particular option.

(Syed, @MichaelHall you might start a chat to hash out the whatever the disagreement and turn it into an answer or edit to the question, as appropriate?)

"I don’t think we have to bet either" Then what is the point of trying to figure out which of two options you would bet on if no have no intention of placing a bet?

@Kaia, I wish I knew how to do that whilst preserving the string of conversation...

This may already have been clarified, but does "we" here mean individually or collectively? I am presuming the former.

@keshlam it’s just an expression: we as in humans in general

Thanks. The answers might have been different if it was "those of us here" or "humanity".

I'm going to answer one aspect of your question:
You ask:

how do we know what our actual degree of belief in a proposition is in the first place?

Two forms of self-knowledge spring to mind: intuition and formalism. That is to say, we can rely on our instincts and the toolbox built from that, and we can also use our formal training. It might help to give an example of each.
When we are dealing with complex phenomena, we might simply intuit our degree of belief. In dealing with a coworker, for instance, we may have very little faith in their ability to complete a task. Thus, we believe they may, but not with a lot of conviction, complete a task. Technically speaking, we are dealing with linguistic epistemic modality as a measure of our belief explicitly by choosing words to represent our inner state. What do we base our choice of words on? Our intuition, instinct, or gut hunch. We might appeal to anecdotes, and a bit of informal reason. It might be a deep fear of the consequences of their poor performance. This would be consistent with the somatic marker hypothesis where our emotional processes.
A second way of determining our degree of belief might be to use statistical methods and formal metrics. Consider how in quality control in manufacturing, we produce a batch of widgets in accordance with some process, and as a follow-up to that process, take a sample of the product, apply measurement, strike out a null hypothesis and then use fancy statistical methods to determine our degree of belief about the quality of the product and our confidence with a confidence interval. Now, we are not just expressing linguistic epistemic modality, but rather relying on the language of mathematics, statistics, and probability distributions to express degree of belief. Consider the language from the WP article on the confidence interval:

"Were this procedure to be repeated on numerous samples, the proportion of calculated 95% confidence intervals that encompassed the true value of the population parameter would tend toward 95%.

That's a lot more precise than "may", "might", or "probably will/won't". But in either case, whether vague natural language or formal statistical language, we are expressing our degree of belief. Ultimately, though, our degree of belief might best be made known, by what sort of action we engage in given the larger framework of our goals and willingness to use the degree of belief to some end, such as winning the bet. In English, we often just use the phrase "put your money where your mouth is" (MW) to convey the idea that one can espouse a degree of belief, but without action, the claim of belief itself might not be accurate.

I revised to include that last paragraph. I think central to your post is the idea that there is often a discontinuity between what people CLAIM they believe, and the real-world RISK they're willing to engage in based what they actually belief. Thus, a person can say that believe you will pay them back, but if you they won't actually lend you money, then presumably they don't. :D

I’m willing to accept this answer since it answers it most directly but since it is still closed and might be reopened, I’ll wait a bit to see other potential answers before doing so

We do, in a sense, make bets like these frequently. Much of the time we aren't betting money as the anticipated unit of benefit isn't monetary, but sometimes it is. We vote with many things, such as our time and effort, or even our mental consideration. So, we can know what bets we do make. In one sense, the resources we "bet" by expending them in alignment with the expected payouts of those beliefs tells us our degree of confidence in that belief.
That being said, people are not always rational people. Consider an actual bet, like playing the lottery. Rationally, most people would admit that the odds of winning are very low, and even given the large potential payout, the certainty of winning would, according to this metric, call for a person to spend only an amount on a ticket that would be less than the actual cost of a ticket. Emotionally, many people feel an impulse which is not rational and choose to make a bet with a cost greater than their confidence in the likelihood of winning. So, this could be seen as a call to align the actual bets you make with the rational evaluation.
You mentioned belief in God. The famous Pascal's Wager attempts to apply this sort of game theory to the question of that belief. If we sufficiently simplify the question as was presented in the wager and consider the position of non-belief to be subject to the same criteria, then the wager works similarly to the model you mentioned. As such, Pascal would argue that the expected payout of non-belief would be 0 units. Therefore, even if you were 100% confident that there were no god, you should bet 0 units since that would still be 100% of the anticipated payoff. Contrary to that, he would argue that the payoff for positive belief would be infinite units. As such, even if you were only 1% certain that God does exist, you would be rational to bet 1% of infinite units, which would itself still be infinite. Therefore, according to the wager, the only time when you should bet less than infinite units is when you are 100% certain that there is no god.
This actually seems somewhat consistent with how people act and accounts for the "no Atheists in foxholes" mentality. Even given extreme emotional and other impetus to disbelieve, most people do not feel 100% certain that there is no god. Therefore, in a time of distress, when other pressures like social pressure seem less important, they find that there is nothing to lose in calling out to a potentially existing god. They may only be 1% confident, but they see no loss in taking that bet, at least in the moment.

+1 We make risky decisions in risky environments all the time. Any such decision is equivalent to (or can be sensibly described as) making a bet.

The problem with Pascal's Wager is that it ignores the fact that religionists require adherents to alter their behavior or believe certain not-God-related things, because "God says so".  Such required behaviors and beliefs might be suboptimal or factually incorrect.

@RonJohn These are not problems in this context. We are talking about people who believe there is a >0% chance that the beliefs are factually correct, not necessarily 100%. Yes, every belief entails other derived beliefs, and these are parts of the cost of the bet. This also doesn't address the question "which God?" It merely shows that, given the presented expected outcomes, "no god" requires a 100% certainty, unlike the alternative. Most people aren't that certain, and therefore, it seems reasonable that they act as they do.

Few "atheists" are that certain.  Maybe we're in a simulation; the being that developed the simulation would be a deistic god, but there's so far no evidence that it wants us to worship it, or that it "stirs the quantum fields" whenever it wants a miracle to occur.

Given that some action didn't actually take place, how do you know what someone would do?
"You ask them. They tell you. Now you know." 
"But wait... How do you really know?"
"You ask them again, what would they really do. They tell you. Now you know what they would really do."
"Yeah... but actually? Would they really actually do it?"
"You ask them again. Would they actually do it? Really actually? They ponder, they actually think it over this time. They tell you. Now you know."
"Yeah, well, but can we ever really, actually believe that?"
"You tell me."
"Well, you know, someone could get second thoughts, before they actually do it, right?"
"Sure, but people don't get second thoughts all the time, right? They tell you what they'll do. Now you know what they'll do. If you want to chip away at that -- go ahead, there are tons of assumptions we take for granted. For instance, we assume they were not lying. We assume that an act of God won't intervene and prevent them from actually doing what they said they would do. We assume the world won't end. We assume there minds were not drugged when they told us. We assume they were not under some hypnotic spell. We don't ask them this while they're sleeping (even though they might give a true answer then). Doesn't any of that matter? The assumption that they were not lying and not under hypnosis seems relevant. But we do generally assume that or know it based on other grounds."
"Yeah, but what if we don't actually ever really know? You know, the know know kind of knowledge."
"As Confucius said: 'Rotten wood cannot be carved, a dung wall cannot be painted. At first, I listened to people's words and trusted they'd act accordingly. Now, I listen to what they say and observe what they do.' So, you observe, learn, and adjust if necessary. That's all there is to it. I have no idea what the heck you mean by 'know know kind of knowledge'."
"Yeah, well, that's because you're not an actual real philosopher. You're only a would-be-wannabe. It may be too deep for you, you know?"

In logical terms, a subjunctive "if p happens, then q would happen (A would do such and so)" is the same as a prediction, "if p, then q will happen".  The truth of a prediction or an implication (p -> q) does not depend on the truth of p; the implication may be (accepted as) true even if p is not true (or not now true, not yet true). The word "actually" actually is only an intensifier which actually presupposes degrees of confidence...

+1 Given your examples in the comments, would you characterize it as the 'subjunctive conditional' and 'factual conditional' respectively?  Because in that language, isn't actually being used to differentiate between a hypothetical and factual linguistic frame of reference? And thus, the function of the word 'actually' isn't expressing a degree of confidence, but rather differentiating between linguistic contexts?

@JD - I think that all depends on the further context. I'd say, sometimes it matters, sometimes it doesn't. My comment also is too simplistic.

It's pretty clear that asking someone what they would do is often different from what they would actually do. People don't have the most accurate models of themselves. We have a tendency to try to represent ourselves and think of ourselves in a more positive light than is true. But when it comes time to act (or bet, in this case), we are often more pragmatically self-interested than we said we would be, or don't have as much confidence in our convictions as we claimed.

@causative -- Indeed, that's why I quoted Confucius... We observe. We base our belief about what some person A tells us they will or would do on how they acted in the past. At least, we'd be wise to do so or otherwise to just wait and see what they do... In one's own case - it's pretty clear that we're all deceiving ourselves a lot of times.

Some things have more evidence than others. Some things seem more obvious than others. Almost everyone, for example, thinks that the world is real, or that we are not all hallucinating, even if we can’t know this for sure. On the other hand, people regularly and commonly think they would do certain things but don’t actually do them. It is easier to claim to “believe” something when there is no consequence attached to being wrong. A consequence may be in the form of losing money in a bet, or something else.

So, if there is more evidence that something happened, will that make it more certain it happened? If not, why care about collecting more evidence? The police found several pieces of evidence - will a confession with details make it more believable that the suspect actually did the crime? The jury still has "reasonable doubt" -- does that not imply degrees of certainty?
